# Distribute python helper application inside other product for developers and users

Tags: python, distribution

Primary product has several python scripts which help users and developers to work with primary application.

I want found way to distribute this scripts with dependencies in following way:

- developers of product should just get a copy of repository, build it, and receive the workable solution. No root access, no downloads acceptable.
- users of product should just get a copy of tar.gz, unpack it, and use. No root access, not downloads, no additional build steps acceptable.
- users of product should just get a rpm/deb packages, install it, and use it. No additional downloads acceptable.

All python distribution way requires the run of additional scripts (it is denied for tar.gz), and then download dependencies often.

So, for my task I need python-fabric with all dependencies.
Right now script wrote with standard python libraries and very ugly, I want switch it to fabric.

How to right support all these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

1. `pip` can install from local tarballs. You could enumerate them in [a requirements file](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#requirements-files); then to install, run from within a virtualenv:

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

   If there are C extensions among dependencies then your developers should have a compiler, python headers installed.
2. [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) could help you bundle a binary distribution for users. If there are no C extensions; it is easy to create the archive with all dependencies ready to use by hand.
3. [pkgme](http://pkgme.net/) might help you to automate packaging for Ubuntu. You could also use [stdeb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb) to manually generate .deb files.

A meaningful `setup.py` describing dependencies, scripts entry points, etc is a prerequisite for all the above.